# How to Show Tooltip when Focusing on TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, tooltip, textfield

I am trying to show a tooltip containing a message on a `TextField` whenever that `TextField` is focused upon. The `TextField` I have already contains a `FocusNode` and the necessary logic to make it work consistently.

I have tried wrapping my `TextField` with a `Tooltip` widget, but this doesn't seem to work in any manner I construct it. Here's my current `ToolTip` wrapper:

`Widget withError(Widget child) => Tooltip( message: record.content[widget.index]['error'], triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.longPress, child: child, );`

Where `child` is a `TextField`. I realize that this should work only when I long-press the `TextField`, not when I focus on it, but I have tried and the long-press mechanic does not work.

I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the HTML title attribute would work for you?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

Comment: @GotStu I'm working with Flutter, not HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: `Builder(
builder: (context) {
final focusNode = FocusNode();
final key = GlobalKey<TooltipState>();
focusNode.addListener(() {
if (focusNode.hasFocus) {
print('ensureTooltipVisible()');
key.currentState?.ensureTooltipVisible();
}
});
return Tooltip(
key: key,
waitDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.manual,
message: 'foo bar',
child: TextField(
focusNode: focusNode,
),
);
}
),
`

Comment: @pskink This solutions works great. Only problem I'm getting right now is a 'RenderBox was not laid out' error for some reason. If I can get that fixed, I'll post a more formal explanation below. It might be good if you could format your response as an answer for me to mark correct, as well. Thanks!

Comment: @pskink, do not answer questions in comments. They can't be accepted, they are a lot more likely to be overlooked by future users looking for them and the question will still be displayed as unanswered in lists which, again, reduces the chance that future users needing the answer will even open the question. And unanswered questions have a lower index score in search results than answered ones, in turn with a lower score than the ones with accepted answers.

Comment: @tao i know, i know, basically I'm too lazy sometimes to write a full answer ;-(